# Is the functor category $[\mathsf C,\mathsf{Ab}]$ algebraic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra

In [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114040/free-objects-in-functor-categories), the functor category $[\mathsf C,\mathsf{Ab}]$ for $\mathsf C$ a small abelian category is examined.

Reading about the acyclic models theorem, I'm wondering about the same functor category when $\mathsf C$ is arbitrary. Is it still algebraic? Are the projective objects still coproducts of representables? What's the left adjoint to the forgetful functor? How much goes through for $\mathsf C$ arbitrary?

More generally, let $\mathsf D$ be an algebraic category. How much algebraic structure does $[\mathsf C,\mathsf D]$ preserve for $\mathsf C$ arbitrary?

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraic" here? Do you mean the nLab definition? If so, what forgetful functor do you have in mind? (Note that on the nLab the definition is stated for a forgetful functor to $\text{Set}$. Also note that if $C$ is large then this functor category may fail to be locally small.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm not really sure about the formalism, but I'm basically asking if Zhen Lin's answer to the linked question holds for $\mathsf C$ an arbitrary category. In particular, does it hold for $\mathsf C=\mathsf{Top}$?

Comment: Everything Zhen wrote works for $C$ an arbitrary small category. Again, in the large case you run into the problem that the functor category may not exist (in the sense that it may not be locally small).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan could you post this as an answer?